# How to select data from SQL Server and save it to my computer

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows

I've selected binary data by its name from database then I showed a `SaveFileDialog` to save that binary data somewhere on my computer.
I wrote the following code to do that but when I opened saved file, there is not any data in it.It just work correctly for txt file. How can I solve this problem?

```
 private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fdTransfer.ShowDialog();
        string filePath = fdTransfer.FileName;
        string fileName=Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        string Ext=Path.GetExtension(fileName);
        string contentType = string.Empty;
        switch (Ext)
        {
            case ".doc":
                contentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
                break;
            case ".docx":
                contentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
                break;
            case ".txt":
                contentType = "application/vnd.ms-txt";
                break;
            case ".xls":
                contentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                break;
            case ".xlsx":
                contentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                break;
            case ".jpg":
                contentType = "image/jpg";
                break;
            case ".png":
                contentType = "image/png";
                break;
            case ".gif":
                contentType = "image/gif";
                break;
            case ".pdf":
                contentType = "application/pdf";
                break;
        }
        if (contentType != String.Empty)
        {

            Byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);             
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertFile",Conn);
            Conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fileName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = contentType;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Content", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;
            int record = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            lblMessage.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully";
            Conn.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lblMessage.Text = "File format not recognised." +
              " Upload Image/Word/PDF/Excel formats";
        }
    }

   private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         try
        {
                   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectFile", Conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    Conn.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fileName;                        string Ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                    if (sdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        sdr.Read();
                        byte[] content = sdr["Content"] as byte[];
                        if (fdDownload.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fdDownload.FileName + Ext
                          , FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
                        fs.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
                        fs.Flush();
                        fs.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                   lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                   lblMessage.Text = "File Downloaded Successfully";
                   Conn.Close();

        }
        catch (SqlException sqlEx)
        {
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lblMessage.Text = "File not  Downloaded Successfully";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `sdr["Content"]` contains data, also you never close / flush the stream.

Comment: Yes,there is <BINARY DATA> in my table in Content column.where should i close my stream?

Comment: I wrote sw.close() but when i opened saved file,there is a error: the file can not be opened because there are problems with contents

Comment: Where `SqlDataRaeader` and `StreamWriter` are closed? Please use `using` statement for `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` and `StreamWriter`.

Comment: if you are storing binary data in database than pass binary parameter and not varchar, 
make sqlDatatype.binary and see if it works

Comment: I added using but there is same error

Comment: I suggest reading this: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ while not directly related more than a half of concepts shown apply.

Comment: dear Friyank the sqldatatype of @FileName is varchar, the sql datatype of Content is binary,so its right.

Comment: I understood that the problem is in following line: byte[] content = sdr["Content"] as byte[]; in this line for any size of file it just can read 200byte of it .for example i upload the file with 367byte it uploaded correctly but when i downloaded it, in this line content is 200byte

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this? Convert the data to byte[] and then write it to the file.

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
if (reader.HasRows)
{
reader.Read();
byte[] content = reader["FileContent"] as byte[];
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\tempfile.txt"
  , FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
fs.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
fs.Flush();
fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: it does not work.when i opened saved file,there is same error

Comment: What is the size of the content byte array?

Comment: And what is the type of file you are trying to open?

Comment: for testing,I defined binary(1000) and I uploaded and then download a docx that have 2 character

Comment: So your column is binary(1000) and you uploaded a valid docx file. Now while downloading you are getting only 2 characters?

Comment: NO, i download the file somewhere on my computer and when i opening it,there is a error : the file can not be opened because there are problem with the contents

Comment: Maybe i upload incorrect content,I added my upload code in above code

Comment: i uploaded and then download a txt that have 2character ,when i opening it,there is a content but not 2 character, its file path displays

Comment: Looks like you are uploading the FileName not the file contents to Database - `byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fdTransfer.FileName.ToString());`

Comment: This blog post may help you - http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-store-and-retrieve-files-from-sql-server-database/ it is using asp.net.

Comment: binary(1000) - i somehow doubt you manage to put a docx file into 1000 bytes.

Comment: thanks, i use File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
It's right for txt file but it doeas'nt work for docx yet.

Comment: Dear Anuraj I understood that the problem is in following line: byte[] content = sdr["Content"] as byte[]; in this line for any size of file it just can read 200byte of it .for example i upload the file with 367byte it uploaded correctly but when i downloaded it, in this line content is 200byte